# C# Switch case use variable out of loop

Tags: c#, variables, switch-statement

So the problem I have is that I have a loop with in the loop a switch statement. And I declare the variable in the loop but out of the switch statement. How can I import it into the switch statement?

Example:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    var detectionid = detectionResult.Sequence.Items[i];
    ulong trackId = detectionid.TrackId;

    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine(trackId);
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine(trackId);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Default case");
            break;
    }
}
```

So `trackId` is the variable I would like to use. But for some reason it will not work and it keeps saying that I have to declare this variable.

PS: I'm a beginner with C# so my knowledge is bare minimum.

EDIT:
here is my full source code

```
 private void OnDetect(CallbackEventArgument callbackArgument)
    {
        if (cameraTemp > 35)
        {
           

            var detectionResult = callbackArgument.GetDetectionResult();
           // var firstDetection = detectionResult.Sequence.Items[0];
           
                foreach (var detection in detectionResult.Sequence.Items)
                {

                    var message = string.Empty;



                

               ImageArgument fullSizeImage = null;
                    switch (detectionResult.Type)
                    {
                        case T3DDetectionType.OBSERVATION:
                            message = "Track ID: " + detection.TrackId;
                            fullSizeImage = detectionResult.RGBImage;
                            break;
                        case T3DDetectionType.DEPTH_LIVENESS:
                        case T3DDetectionType.THERMAL_LIVENESS:
                            message = "Track ID: " + detection.TrackId + " Score: " + (detection as Liveness).Score.ToString("N0");
                            

                            score = (detection as Liveness).Score.ToString("N0");
                            fullSizeImage = detectionResult.FullImage;



                            break;
                        case T3DDetectionType.TEMPERATURE:
                            message = "Temperature: " + (detection as Temperature).MeasurementValueCelsius.ToString("N1") + "°C";
                        temperature = (detection as Temperature).MeasurementValueCelsius.ToString("N1") + "°C";
                        //float temperature = (detection as Temperature).MeasurementValueCelsius;
                        fullSizeImage = detectionResult.FullImage;

                       


                        break;

                    }



                for (int i = 0; i < detectionResult.Sequence.Items.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var detectionid = detectionResult.Sequence.Items[i];
                    double depth = detectionid.Depth/1000.00 ;
                    ulong trackId = detectionid.TrackId;

                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0:

                            

                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
                            /* https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/WriteJsonWithJsonTextWriter.htm */
                            using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                            {
                                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;


                                writer.WritePropertyName(trackId.ToString());
                                writer.WriteStartArray();
                                writer.WriteStartObject();
                                writer.WritePropertyName("Temperature");
                                writer.WriteValue(temperature);
                                writer.WritePropertyName("Depth");
                                writer.WriteValue(depth);
                                writer.WritePropertyName("TrackId");
                                writer.WriteValue(trackId);
                                writer.WriteEndObject();
                                writer.WriteEnd();
                            }
                            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:/Users/Kimeru/Documents/Dermalog Noah WPF/data" + trackId + ".json", sb.ToString());
                            break;

                        case 1:
                           
                            break;
                        

                        case 2:
                            
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                            break;
                    }
                }




                ClearDetectCanvas(detectionResult.Type);
                    UpdateDetectImages(fullSizeImage, detection.Portrait);
                    UpdateDetectCanvas(fullSizeImage, detection);
                    UpdateLabel(detectionResult.Type, message);

                    var trackIDs = callbackArgument.GetTrackIDs().ToList();
                    if (trackIDs.Count > 0)
                    {
                        UpdateTrackStatus(callbackArgument.GetDetectionItemsForTrack(trackIDs.First()));
                    }

                }
            }
        
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `double ulong`, use `var`.

Comment: was a wrong paste from my code, I changed it!

Comment: Now that you fixed the type there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code.  Can you reproduce the issue if you just do `ulong trackId = 5;`?  Also can you include the exact error that you get.

Comment: still not working, it says "Cannot use local variable 'trackId' before it is declared"

Comment: It seems that you omitted some code necessary to reproduce the issue. If you search backwards from the line `ulong trackId = detectionid.TrackId;` do you find another occurrence of `trackId`?

Comment: The things it that this gets data from a heat camera (SDK), but if I debug I see that it gives the right value to it, the only problem is just using the variable in the switch stement

Comment: I just reproduced a testing scenario so it would be possible to understand it, because there is a lot going on.

Comment: The error "Cannot use local variable 'trackId' before it is declared" is a compiler error - how are you able to debug if you cannot compile? And I'm sure it has nothing to do with the switch statement but with some code you did not show yet.

Comment: if i place it in the switch statement i can debug but the problem then is that i can't use it in the other cases (2 and 3)

Comment: Again: the code you posted is perfectly fine. You need to post code that shows your problem.

Comment: Where are score and temperature declared?

Comment: After adding the missing declarations, the code compiles just fine. Frankly, I already spent too much time on your question without getting what your actual problem is. You really have to provide some code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `double ulong` type.

- `double` is a [floating point type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)
- `ulong` is an [integral numeric type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)

Use the correct type or use `var` to let the compiler infer the type.

```
var trackId = detectionid.TrackId;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in declaration of trackId. You should use either ulong or double, not both at the same time.

```
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var detectionid = detectionResult.Sequence.Items[i];
                ulong trackId = detectionid.TrackId;
                // or
                //double trackId = detectionid.TrackId;
                // or
                //var trackId = detectionid.TrackId;
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine(trackId);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine(trackId);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                        break;
                }
            }
```